# How to set an object to Firebase Firestore - Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, object, google-cloud-firestore

i have tried to save an object to firebase from javascript with no success, i have tried, as an array, also as an array of objects, and always stores the value as ZERO, i mean 0, not sure why is this happening, following the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web_2) i can see it should be possible to store objects and arrays, but it won't work as expected.

Here is my array:

```
let paxRoom = { "20": { "room": 20, "paxNumber": 2 }, "23": { "room": 23, "paxNumber": 2 } }
```

and here how is save it:

```
const newGuestProfile = await firebase.firestore()
                .collection("hpp")
                .doc(self.userType)
                .collection("profile")
                .doc(newUser.user.uid)
                .set({
                  paxExtraRoom: paxRoom | null,
                })
```

It doesn't show any errors on console... and what's stored is this:

[image: Preview]

I have also tried storing the data as an array using the room number as index, but happens the same, turns into ZERO, stored as number data Type.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having a javascript problem, not a firebase problem, test this in your console and you will get yourself the answer:

```
const a = {} | null // 0
const b = {} || null // {}
```

Cheers!